# SQL Query Update with Select

Tags: sql, oracle

I wish to update a record by setting the values through an select statemenet..

The query should look something like this;

```
UPDATE FCR.HEADER
SET (Value1,Value2,Value3)

(SELECT sum(AMOUNT_FC),sum(AMOUNT_DC ), value1 
FROM tableA
WHERE DATE = to_date('02/05/2006', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
GROUP BY UNIT_ID, TRX_DATE)

WHERE TRX_DATE = to_date('02/05/2006', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
AND column14 = 'some value'
```

What is the proper format in order for this query to work ?

Comment: could you describe the contents of HEADER and tableA? Are you trying to extract ONE line from tableA and to put the values in all rows of table HEADER?

Comment: @cgval: What is `value1`? A table column? A computed column? A parameter in a proceudre?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE FCR.HEADER
SET Value1 = (SELECT sum(AMOUNT_FC)
        FROM tableA
        WHERE DATE = to_date('02/05/2006', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
        GROUP BY UNIT_ID, TRX_DATE),

Value2 = (SELECT sum(AMOUNT_DC)
        FROM tableA
        WHERE DATE = to_date('02/05/2006', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
        GROUP BY UNIT_ID, TRX_DATE),
Value3 = (SELECT sum(AMOUNT_DC)
        FROM tableA
        WHERE DATE = to_date('02/05/2006', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
        GROUP BY UNIT_ID, TRX_DATE)

WHERE TRX_DATE = to_date('02/05/2006', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
AND column14 = 'some value'
```

it would be better to have a Variable of type Date to hold to_date(...).

Hope this helps.